# Does down voting an answer lose you rep points

Tags: support

When reviewing the recent answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/what-are-the-best-practices-for-managing-changing-picklist-values-in-managed-pac/50468#50468), I down voted the answer and left a comment. After that I lost a reputation point. I'm still learning all the dos and don'ts of the stack exchange but the only options I had for the "First Posts" review is to down vote or comment, and after the down vote a comment is requested. What is the proper way to review something like this or did something else happen to cause the loss of a point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general discussion of downvoting and the rep lose in [Why do you lose reputation for down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting).

Basically, there has to be some repercussion for downvoting or users could abuse the feature.

A comment is a good starting point. If you feel strongly that that an answer is wrong, downvote it. Downvoting without a comment is bad form IMHO. You aren't giving the answerer any opportunity to respond to the criticism or modify the answer accordingly.

Of course, that is just a suggestion. You are free to vote as you see fit.

Comment: That makes sense, what is best practice?  Just comment, especially if it's a new user?

Comment: I'd say start with a comment. You can always vote down later. For the non-answer linked in your question flagging as not an answer is probably the best approach. I'm not sure what happens to the vote down rep if an admin then deletes the answer.

Comment: Well it did end up getting deleted and the point was restored, good to know. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong!

Comment: @JennyB Nope, you're going along the right lines :) Spotted your earlier in this list: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter Off to a great start on SFSE, good to have you around!